# Why use micro-averaged ROC curve

Tags: roc, multiclass-classification

As I read through articles about which metric to choose, I found out that when a dataset is imbalanced, PR curve is preferred over ROC curve.

Eg. Given an imbalanced multiclass-classification dataset that has class A:50 instances, B: 200 instances, and C: 50 instances, clearly that instances of class B is 4 times the instances of class A and C. Thus the model will bias towards predicting class B. So, class A and C will have higher TN:

1. However, neither precision nor recall cares about the true negatives, thus using PR curve is a fair choice.
2. The model prediction will result in low false positive rate (which is what we want) but also low true positive rate (what we don't like to see) for class A and C, therefore as long as we found out that the dataset is imbalanced, we shouldn't use ROC curve. And since we don't use ROC curve for imbalanced dataset, what's the purpose of having micro-averaged ROC curve (for multiclass classification)? Note that micro-average ROC is the sum of true positive rate divided by the sum of false positive rate. In other words, each class will have a weightage.

Comment: You might want to check this question at the Data Science Stack Exchange site: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin